# ReactJS : useMemo hook fixed my infinite rerender issue instead of useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-usememo, react-usecallback

## Without useMemo : infinite rerendering component

I had an issue with the code below compiling successfully but rerendering the component infinite times and I get this error in console : `Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.`

```
import { Box, Flex } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Section, { SectionHeading } from "../../components/UI/Section";

import FaqList from "../../data/FaqList";
import FAQFilterBtn from "./FAQFilterBtn";
import FAQItems from "./FAQItems";

const allFaqItems = Object.values(FaqList).map((elem) => elem.content);

const allFaq = allFaqItems.map((elem, index) => (
  <Box key={index}>
    <FAQItems items={elem} faqHeading={Object.values(FaqList)[index].heading} />
  </Box>
));

const FAQSection = () => {
  const [displayList, setDisplayList] = useState(allFaq);
  const [activeFilter, setActiveFilter] = useState("All");

  const filteredAllFaq = 
      allFaqItems.map((elem, index) => {
        const faq =
          activeFilter === Object.values(FaqList)[index].heading ||
          activeFilter === "All" ? (
            elem.length ? (
              <FAQItems
                items={elem}
                faqHeading={Object.values(FaqList)[index].heading}
              />
            ) : (
              ""
            )
          ) : (
            ""
          );
        return <Box key={index}>{faq}</Box>;
      });

  const changeFilter = (filter: string) => {
    setActiveFilter(filter);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setDisplayList(filteredAllFaq);
  }, [activeFilter, filteredAllFaq]);

 
  console.log(activeFilter);

  return (
    <Section id="#faq-section">
      <>
        <Flex w="full" justify="space-between">
          <SectionHeading mb={0}>Frequently asked questions</SectionHeading>
        </Flex>

        <Flex m={4} mb={-4} gap={6}>
          <FAQFilterBtn
            name="All"
            active={activeFilter}
            setFilter={changeFilter}
          />
          {FaqList.map((e, index) => (
            <FAQFilterBtn
              key={index}
              name={e.heading}
              active={activeFilter}
              setFilter={changeFilter}
            />
          ))}
        </Flex>

        {displayList}
      </>
    </Section>
  );
};

export default FAQSection;
```

So I tried using the `useEffect` hook with a dependency on the changing filter (activeFilter)  which would cause the component to rerender only one time but it doesn't. I tried using the `useCallback` hook since setStates are asynchronous but it didn't help.

---

## With useMemo : issue seems "fixed"

Then I thought it had something to do with the `filteredAllFaq` being an `array.map()` which might be an "expensive/high load function" so I decided to go with `useMemo` hook which seemed to fixed the issue. Code below :

```
  const filteredAllFaq = useMemo(() => allFaqItems.map((elem, index) => {
    const faq =
      activeFilter === Object.values(FaqList)[index].heading ||
      activeFilter === "All" ? (
        elem.length ? (
          <FAQItems
            items={elem}
            faqHeading={Object.values(FaqList)[index].heading}
          />
        ) : (
          ""
        )
      ) : (
        ""
      );
    return <Box key={index}>{faq}</Box>;
  }), [activeFilter]);

  const changeFilter = (filter: string) => {
    setActiveFilter(filter);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setDisplayList(filteredAllFaq);
  }, [activeFilter, filteredAllFaq]);

  console.log(activeFilter);
```

**Even though it fixed the rerendering issue, I feel like I'm using it the wrong way and the whole component could be done much better.


There's also a small issue after my "fix" because it seems to render/console.log(activeFilter) exactly 4 times at mount and whenever `activeFilter` changes. I was expecting it to render only once.**

I'm new to React and have never used `useMemo` before. I tried searching for a solution but I don't even know where my problem is. Any advice is very much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of defining `filteredAllFaq` as a `const` in the function body, you can store its value in a `useState` hook. The `displayList` state hook is useless and causes the problem. So replace that with

```
const [filteredAllFaq, setFilteredAllFaq] = useState(allFaq);
```

When you want to change `filteredAllFaq` value, do it in the `useEffect` hook like this (not in the function body):

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const newFilteredAllFaq = allFaqItems.map((elem, index) => {
      const faq =
        activeFilter === Object.values(FaqList)[index].heading ||
          activeFilter === "All" ? (
          elem.length ? (
            <FAQItems
              items={elem}
              faqHeading={Object.values(FaqList)[index].heading}
            />
          ) : (
            ""
          )
        ) : (
          ""
        );
      return <Box key={index}>{faq}</Box>;
    });
    
    setFilteredAllFaq(newFilteredAllFaq);
  }, [activeFilter]);
```

Consider that `filteredAllFaq` dependency of `useEffect` has been removed and `activeFilter` dependency is enough for updating `filteredAllFaq` state.

---

As for the case that `console.log` is executed four times. These extra rerenders could be the result of `reactStrictMode` which is wrapped around the main project component (usually located in index.js file). If you remove that wrapper, extra rerenders will be stopped.

Comment: Wow thank you so much ! It works perfectly and the code is much cleaner without the `useMemo` hook.

Disabling `reactStrictMode` reduced the console.logs from 4 to 2, so I suppose it still renders the component twice. Not an issue tho since everything works great!